# On the nonexistence of linear actions of $PGL(k)$ on $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, representation-theory, lie-groups, group-cohomology

Let our field be $\mathbb{C}$ and let $PGL(k)=GL(k)$ for $k>1$.  I want to show the nonexistence of a linear action of $PGL(k) \curvearrowright \mathbb{C}^n$.

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
Clearly $H_2(PGL(k),\Z)=H_2(B(PGL(k)),\Z)=H_2(BGL(k),\Z) \neq 0$.  According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation) this should be an obstruction to a homomorphism from $PGL(k) \to GL(n)$.  Where is a good place to find this fact that is probably standard?

Comment: You definitely have the trivial action. Do you just want a nontrivial action or are there any other properties you want?

Comment: Thank you.  I want a nontrivial action - the triviality of the action implies triviality of any $PGL(k)$ equivariant line bundle with sections $\mathbb C^n$, over $\mathbb{P}^{k-1}$, so I am not interested in this case. (I am trying to show the nonexistence of any $PGL$ equivariant line bundle over projective space.)

Comment: I don't think that there is a nontrivial action, and I would be delighted to be proved wrong :).

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your question correctly, but every linear algebraic group is isomorphic to a closed subgroup of a general linear group. In particular there exists an injective homomorphism $PGL(k) \to GL(n)$ (with $n$ depending on $k$).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$
As always we have the adjoint representation $PGL(k+1) \to GL(Lie(PGL(k+1)))$  where $Lie(PGL(k+1))=gl(k+1)/\C\langle Id \rangle \cong sl_{k+1}$.

It sends $A \in PGL(k+1)$ to $ad_{\tilde A}$ where $\tilde A$ is any lift to $GL(k+1)$.  Thus $n$ can be chosen to be $(k^2+k)^2$.  So these actions do exist.